# ubuntu create partition block more than 4k

Tags: linux, diskspace

I'm at Ubuntu 11.10 64 and I'm developing an application in C that creates tons of files in tons of directories. I'm trying to calculate what is lighter, create some big file in some folders or tons of small files in tons of folders. I know the answer will be some big files in some directories.

I'm trying to calculate in which partition block size I'll store my date in less space, how do I change or create a new partition with other block size greater than the default 4k of the ext4?

Comment: Can you describe the task with more detail? What is the data? What kind of access is more typical (read/write; random/sequential)? Your data will always take the same size as data itself has (if there is no compression at FS level), only meta-information  can take different part of space.

Comment: Squid (the caching web-proxy) uses a lot of nested directories, around 16 directories of next level in the current; with 3 or 4 levels totally. In the lower lewel there are a lot of small files.

Comment: read and write, random, the data is random binary, normally the same size

Comment: Frederico Schardong, if the data size is fixed or predictable (e.g.  slow growing), use several longer files (just like rainbow tables). You can use `fallocate` function and any fs with [extents](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extent_(file_systems)): ext4, btrfs, JFS, XFS. Even with 4kb block size: "A single extent in ext4 can map up to 128 MiB of contiguous space".

Answer (score 0):

Try with `mkfs.ext4` (for 8k block size):

```
# mkfs.ext4 -j -b 8192 /dev/sda3
```

Comment: sudo mount -t ext4 /dev/sda10 md5cracker
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sda10